# Почему переменная не является функцией

Tags: javascript

В первом случае (закомментированом) все нормально работает, но когда пытаюсь присвоить переменной onReady функцию через сеттер, то в setTimeout пишет что это не функция. Почему так? Ведь я в обоих случаях присваиваю переменной функцию.

```js
function CoffeeMachine(power, capacity) {

  // var onReady = function() {
  //     console.log( 'Кофе готов!' );
  //   }

  var onReady;
  this.set = function(f) {
    onReady = f;
  };

  this.run = function() {
     setTimeout(onReady, 1000);
  };
}

var coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine(20000, 500);
coffeeMachine.run();

coffeeMachine.set(function() {
  console.log( 'Готов кофе' );
});
```

Comment: Потому, что `set` нужно вызывать ДО `run`

Comment: Потому что присваиваешь после того как пытаешься первый раз использовать. Вызов сеттера подними выше чтоб он был до вызова run.

Comment: так onReady вызывается через 1000 мс же, я думал значение через 1000мс заносится

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ onReady(); }, 1000);`

Comment: значит setTimeout сперва читает функцию, а потом выполняет? из-за этого не получается?

Comment: `setTimeout` запоминает ссылку на функцию, которая подается первым параметром, и вызывает ее через 1 секунду. Но в Вашем коде ему подается `undefined`, так как переменная `onReady` еще не назначена.

Comment: понял,, спасибо